# Need only border for arrow not color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement arrow as below.

For that I need only border not color

Please check this link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6556rw/)

```css
.pointer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
  }
  .pointer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  }
  .pointer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pointer">
    
</div>
```

I am expecting to be like below image[image: this]

Comment: The background needs to be transparent or could be white? (not that I have the answer, but just to start trying).

Comment: I updated the question @azeós

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use before, after and transform skew. Gives you more flexibility.

```css
.arrow{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
min-width:100px;
padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem;
text-align:center;
line-height:2;
min-height:2rem;
}
.arrow:before,.arrow:after{
  content:" ";
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:-1px;
  border:2px solid red;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}
.arrow:before{
 border-bottom:0;
 transform:skewX(45deg);
}
.arrow:after{
 border-top:0;
 top:50%;
 transform:skewX(-45deg);
}

.left:before{ transform:skewX(-45deg);}
.left:after{transform:skewX(45deg);}

.blue:before,.blue:after{border-color:blue;}

.bgpink:before,.bgpink:after{background-color: pink}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="arrow left"> to the left </div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="arrow left blue"> and change border color </div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="arrow left blue bgpink"> and change bg color too </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

option 1: use svg instead, work only in moden broswers

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L110 10 L100 20 L0 20 L10 10 Z" fill="transparent" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

option 2: use border, you can change value to make it more smooth

```css
.arrow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-43px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.708);
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.arrow:before {}

.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(42px) rotate(45deg) scale(0.708);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

option 3: use svg as background

```css
.arrow {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="200" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0 L100 0 L110 10 L100 20 L0 20 L10 10 Z" fill="transparent" stroke="red"/></svg>');
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I need only using basic html attributes i.e. div/p/... Our app is like if we click squre, div becomes square. Similarly if we click rectangle it will become rectangle...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pointer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
  }
  .pointer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  }
  .pointer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  }
  .pointer2 {
    width: 194px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    background:white;
    top:2px;
    left:4px
  }
  .pointer2:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 18px solid red;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  }
  .pointer2:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -18px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 18px solid white;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pointer">
<div class="pointer2">
</div>
    
</div>
```

Try with two pointers. I think this is the only one solution with css

Comment: I updated the question. I dont require blue background. PLease check the image attached

Comment: Yes, its the same. Can you try with only one div. Because, those divs are generated dynamically i.e. they will be dragged and dropped so I need to change the complete code

Comment: @Kartheeks I don't thing it as possible. I tried my best. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Data URIs` to give an inline `svg` background using **CSS** like below. No need to change in **HTML**

```css
.pointer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pointer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='21' height='41' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M0 0 L20 20 L0 40' fill='transparent' stroke='red'/></svg>");
}

.pointer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -21px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='21' height='41' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M0 0 L20 20 L0 40' fill='transparent' stroke='red'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer"></div>
```